# Kotlin/Java - Non-existent reference in Java annotation on property parameter of constructor compiles

Tags: java, maven, kotlin, intellij-idea, annotations

In my company, we're starting to mix Kotlin with Java and found a curious scenario. When I place a Java annotation on a property parameter of a constructor in a Kotlin class, and use a non-existent reference as one of the annotation's parameters, IntelliJ visually indicates an error, but both its build (Ctrl+F9) and maven's build compile normally, without errors.

We're using Java 8 and Kotlin 1.4.20.

Here's the annotation, declared as a Java file:

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface Required {

    String scope() default "ABC";
}
```

And here's the Kotlin class using the annotation (class `Abc` does not exist):

```kotlin
data class Test(
        // Compiles normally
        @Required(scope = Abc.X)
        val text: String
) {

    // Compilation error
    @Required(scope = Abc.X)
    fun x() {

    }
}
```

As mentioned in the code comments, the same annotation placed in a Kotlin function behaves as expected (that is, the code does not compile). An equivalent annotation declared as a Kotlin file also behaves as expected.

When the code is run, the `scope` variable assumes its default value, so there are no runtime errors.

I've already tried to:

- Invalidate IntelliJ cache and restart.
- Switch the annotation declaration from `@Required(scope = Abc.X)` to `@field:Required(scope = Abc.X)`

I also tried to replicate the behaviour in a brand new project without inheriting from the company's base maven project, but to no avail.

Honestly, I think there's a huge possibility that it is something related to the company's project. I know I haven't specified what my company uses and all the configuration (in fact, the question would get way too big if I did that), but I hope that even with just the basic problem someone may be able to help.

Comment: I could not reproduce this with the 2020.3.1 Preview version from https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+2020.3+latest+builds and latest Kotlin plugin. Can you provide a sample project?

Comment: Failed to reproduce from your sample code, but looks like this bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-33822

Comment: @AlexeyBelkov Yeah, that's it. One thing that was different was that my annotation does not have `@Target(FIELD)`, but on closer inspection I needed to add it to cause the bug. I'm gonna update the question to consider this. Also, I changed the `scope` property to a non-existent one, as mentioned in the bug, and it does compile.

If you want to post your answer, I'll gadly accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Kotlin compiler bug: argument list is not analyzed for usage of Java annotation with `@Target(FIELD)` on Kotlin property.

For updates on this please follow the issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-33822.